# Customize log4j log manager to include a prefix in all logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

In my project I've various different modules and for all logging they profile a prefix in the message for isolation. For instance

private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

Project 1 all logs :

```
log.info("{} my message my args{}", Project1.KEY, args);
```

Project 2 all logs :

```
log.info("{} my message my args{}", Project2.KEY, args);
```

Instead of manually supplying the key, how can each module configure the `LogManager` so the key prefix is automatically appended to each message?

I was able to workaround this by extending the `AbstractMessageFactory` by this approach is require a lot of same code duplication in each module

```
public class CustomLogManager extends LogManager {

    private static final class CustomMessageFactory extends AbstractMessageFactory {

        public static final CustomMessageFactory INSTANCE = new CustomMessageFactory();

        private String messageWithPrefix(String message) {
            return prefix + SEPARATOR + message;
        }

        @Override
        public Message newMessage(String message, Object... params) {
            return new ParameterizedMessage(messageWithPrefix(message), params);
        }

        @Override
        public Message newMessage(final String message, final Object p0) {
            return new ParameterizedMessage(messageWithPrefix(message), p0);
        }

        ... other overloads ...

    }

    private static final Prefix prefix = Prefix.one;

    public static Logger getLogger(final Class<?> clazz) {
        return getLogger(clazz, CustomMessageFactory.INSTANCE);
    }

}
```

Would it be feasible to customize the `ParameterizedMessageFactory` to just include a prefix string?

Comment: The challenge with your question is "what is a module"? Is it a simple jar file in the same classloader as all other jars? Is it a Java module in the Java Platform Module System? Is it some some sort of other plugin?  Log4j has a few ways I could think of to do this but without understanding how to determine which module is "active" it is difficult to answer.

Comment: @rgoers they are different projects in a gradle setup. See https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/ . Each project is defining its own `build.gradle`

Comment: Ok. So I assume this is the same as a maven multi-module project and you are producing multiple jars.

Comment: Yes correct. All are produced as individual jar thought i don't think i can customize log4j2.xml as that is built in common framework.

Answer (score 0):

Given your circumstances I would create an interface that contains the information you are looking for along with a key - perhaps a package name that is unique to each jar (I hope you don't co-mingle package names across jars). I would then create an instance of that interface in every jar and register it as a service in conformance with java.util.ServiceLoader.

I would then create a Log4j2 Lookup that uses ServiceLoader to find all the instances and add them to a Map during initialization. I would then use that lookup in my Log4j configuration to lookup the appropriate value using the Logger in the LogEvent (assuming the Loggers follow the convention of using a class name for their name).